# Best way to make a bi-directional array?

Tags: php

I'm not sure if "bidirectional" is the best name for it, but I want a data structure where both the key and the data are unique pairs. For example: a=1,b=2,c=3... and I want to be able to call the variables in either direction (what is the number for "a"? what is the letter for 3?). I feel like this should be a pretty easy task, but I'm drawing a blank. The best I can come up with is something like array("a"=>1,1=>"a","b"=>2,2=>"b"...). There's a better way of doing this other than storing each pair twice, right?

Comment: I think you should accept one of the answers if you are satisfied :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use array_flip

Furthermore, you can merge your original array with the flipped one.

```
$original = array ( ... );
$extended = array_merge($original, array_flip($original));
```

If you do not want to duplicate the data but keep transparency:

```
function dosearch($array, $needle) {
    if (isset($array[$needle])) 
        return $array[$needle];

    $tmparray=array_flip($array);
    if (isset($tmparray[$needle]))
        return $tmparray[$needle];

    return false; //nothing found
}
```

This should be both transparent and performer, since you flip as necessary.
(Thank you @imsiso for inspiration)

Comment: +1 - this would be better if you want to access to arrays multiple times. but you should keep double data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_filter, like this:

```
$arr = array(
              "a"=>1,
              "b"=>2,
              "c"=>3
              );
$filtered_arr = array_filter($arr, function($item) { return( $item == "3" ); } );
print_r($filtered_arr);
```

There is no native support for a "bi-directional" dictionary in PHP, but you can wrap this up into an upgraded array.

You should check what's the most efficient method (you saw there are many comments here specifying ways to do so).

Edit: It's better in performance than array_flip since it's not duplicating the array only searching it.